# Fortran library that would enable me to capture arrow key movement

Tags: windows-7, fortran, windows-xp, intel-fortran

I would like to use arrow keys to move some points in a QuickWin plot in my console applications. Is there a library out there providing support for something like that?

Comment: Can you define "ivf" please?

Comment: "ivf" is an unnecessary new tag, I've removed it and replaced it with an established, and more informative, equivalent tag.

Comment: Does Intel support [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)?

Comment: @wallyk - If it does, I cannot find many docs about it.

Comment: See if you can get [this](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/ncurses.htm) to work.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few function calls supported by quickwin:  try incharqq, getcharqq or peekcharqq.  You'll have to write a noddy program to find out what the key sequences for the arrow keys are.

The call that you may be missing is passdirkeysqq with the parameter PASS_DIR_TRUE.  This will enable you to see the direction keys.  Each one comes out as 2 keys with the lead character being 224.

If you are not getting any success with this, try using the numeric keypad.

Comment: Not near my working machine at this moment, but as soon as I get back (end of week) I'm gonna check this out.